# TV show with a teenage kid who could turn into a dragon

Tags: story-identification, tv, dragons, animation

I remember watching an animated TV show mid 2000’s where there was this teenage kid who could turn into a dragon. He kept his human form but gained abilities of a dragon. I very roughly remember this one episode where a whole bunch of dragons attacked the high school he was going to.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SciFi.SE! So this boy looked like a normal human, but could fly and breathe fire? What exactly were the "_abilities of a dragon_" he gained? Also do you remember what type of animation this was? Cartoon, CGI, or some other form of animation?

Comment: Hello, thank you. And Yeah from what I remember he kept human form (2 legs, 2 arms, torso, head) I remember he would grow scales on his body. I remember him being able to breath fire, he got super strength, and speed but couldn’t fly. And if I remember right it was a cartoon

Answer (score 10):

The TV show I’ve been searching for is called [Firebreather](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Firebreather_(film)). It was a cartoon on Cartoon Network I believe.

> On the last day of the war between humans and Kaiju, a human woman named Margaret Rosenblatt and Belloc, the dragon-like Kaiju king, fall in love, and become parents to a hybrid son named Duncan.
>
> Sixteen years later, Margaret and Duncan are moving into a new house as he prepares to attend a new school. However, Duncan fears that his Kaiju-like appearance and abilities will make him a target for bullies. At school, he quickly develops a crush on a popular girl Jenna and makes an enemy out of her ex-boyfriend Troy Adams. In biology class, Duncan befriends fellow outcasts Kenny and Isabel, the latter who happens to be a Kaiju-obsessed fangirl and develops a crush on him.

Comment: You can accept an answer by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour]. As a self-answer, you won't be able to complete that process until 48 hours after when you asked the question, but clicking earlier will let you know how much time is left.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds a lot like American Dragon: Jake Long. This show was on the Disney Channel, the character was able to transform fully into a dragon.

He could transform only some parts of his body, so that he could maintain a human form but have dragon wings or dragon claws. A [complete list of his powers may be found here](https://hero.fandom.com/wiki/Jake_Long#Powers).

Comment: Did (or could) he keep his human form but gain abilities of a dragon, as described in the question?

Comment: He could transform only some parts of his body, so that he could maintain a human form but have dragon wings or dragon claws. A complete list of his powers may be found here: [link](https://hero.fandom.com/wiki/Jake_Long#Powers)